# Cómo enviar al LocalStorage un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, angular, poo, objeto

estoy realizando una aplicación con Angular  en la misma tengo algunas cards que contienen un botón llamado (add favourite) , que al darle click tienen que enviar el objeto presionado al localstorage.

Comienzo explicando , la aplicación pide extrae los datos de los objetos de una api , crea los objectos y los inserta dentro de un array que contiene mas de 300 objetos, luego la aplicación tiene un filtro de busqueda donde en el cual podré buscar el nombre del personaje y si ese nombre coincide con algun nombre de los objectos que se encuentran dentro de mi array , se mostrará una card con la imagen del personaje y boton que dice add favourite.

Lo que quiero saber es como hacer para crear un array dentro del localstorage y luego  que dentro de ese array se vayan agregando los personajes que el usuario los fue clickeando como favoritos. La función se llama enviarfav y está vacia.

Además luego tendria que verificar si ese personaje ya fue enviado al local, para que no se me agregué dos veces a a la sección favoritos ya que luego mostraré todos los personajes que el usuario tiene como favorito en una tabla

Comment: Hola @Treviño, ¿y eso que le quitó el código a la pregunta?

Answer (score 6):

Como tal, no puedes guardar un array, ya que *localStorage* solo admite strings, un protocolo : `String(Clave, Valor)`, pero hay alternativas como `JSON.stringify`

No te recomiendo guardar un array tan largo en *localStorage*, de todas maneras, puedes hacerlo con `JSON.stringify`, este método convierte objetos o arrays a strings

```javascript
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(array));
```

Puedes devolverlo con `JSON.parse`

```
let localstoragearr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key"))
```

---

Puedes comprobar si existe en *localStorage* de manera muy sencilla:

> Un item que no existe en localStorage y se trata de obtener con getItem() da null

Entonces, simplemente, podemos hacer:

```javascript
if (localStorage.getItem("key") === null) {
    // El item no existe
}
```

Comment: Para leer los datos guardados está `JSON.parse`, el análogo a `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @treviño-susana-alo, ya queda de tu parte verificar cuales items ya estan agregados, etc. toma en cuenta que por cada item que selecciones deberas hacer una consulta a tu localStorage.